# Type of transformer

Tags: pcb, transformer

I am using the circuit below to drive the [ADC3422](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc3422.pdf) ADC I am using. I was wondering what type of transformer I would need. The data sheet (Fig. 185) doesn't specify anything and I am not sure how to choose one.

[image]

Comment: Pick one that handles your input frequency with minimal distortion. Did you miss the caption that says "*Driving Circuit Design: Input Frequencies Between 100 MHz to 230 MHz*"? The datasheet has other circuits for other frequency ranges.

Comment: Have a look at minicircuits.com, they have a section on transformers. Each is given a frequency range for which it is designed to work.

Answer (score 2):

In general for a **starting point** on this kind of thing you can look up any available evaluation board for the component in question (ADC3422), find the manual, design files, and the bill of materials.

This will also yield invaluable information on layout and bypassing etc. since the manufacturer has every reason to show off their component in the best possible light.

I won't give away the specific result in the case of the transformer, but Neil_UK has nailed it.